# Handling exceptions in breeze

Tags: breeze

Does anyone know how to handle exception sent from server? It might be unauthorized exception or no response from server as well.

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Partners");
manager.executeQuery(query, function (data) {
............
}
```

Data is being fetched using the code very well. I just want to add a exception handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... In the function failed it throws the exception message

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Partners");
manager.executeQuery(query).then(success).fail(failed)

function success(data){

}
function failed(error){

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! This works fine but it does not work if there is no response from server. Do you know how to set a time so that it will fail if client does not receive response within a time period?